# Django i18n find supported languages

Tags: python, django, internationalization, locale

I'm determining a user's language preference through some third party service he's also registered at. This service provides me with a locale code (e.g. `en_US`). If I do not have the corresponding language code in `settings.LANGUAGES`, does Django provide some integrated (simple) way to determine the best fallback choise from `settings.languages` (e.g. `en-gb`).

Of course I know I could do a couple of string comparisons of the locale code etc by myself, just being curious if there's a handier solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the code Django uses to determine the language based on a request [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L348). Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a handy utility function for what you're doing. The logic used is trivial however -- just [lop the end off](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L367) if the sub-language isn't supported and search for the main language as a fallback. This wouldn't get you from `en-us` to `en-gb` however.

Incidentally, the [`to_locale`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L38) and [`to_language`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L55) functions in that file might be of interest to you.